# WPF trigger from a different control

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to change the containing border background color based on the focus property of a contained textbox. Can someone explain what's the problem with my code?

```
<Border BorderBrush="LightBlue" BorderThickness="2" Background="#33000000">
    <Border.Style>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger
                  Binding="{Binding IsFocused, ElementName=txtValue}"
                  Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Border.Background" Value="Green" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Border.Style>
    <Grid Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox Name="txtValue" Grid.Column="0" Text="20" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"  />
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your DataTrigger is not change the value of the **Background** property because you set it inside the Border declaration. So, once setted, it will never changed. To allow changing, you have to set the value inside the Style.

```
 <Border BorderBrush="LightBlue" BorderThickness="2" >
    <Border.Style>            
        <Style TargetType="Border">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#33000000"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsFocused, ElementName=txtValue}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Border.Style>
    <Grid Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox Name="txtValue" Grid.Column="0" Text="20" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"  />
    </Grid>
</Border>
```