# Conditional binding in a template using dependency properties

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datatrigger

I have a button that has four dependency properties, each representing a state the button is in.  Each state's source is an image.  What I would like to achieve is an ability for any state other than `NormalState` to bind to `NormalState's` value if it's own value was not provided.

I tried doing it using `DataTrigger`, but I'm getting an exception:

`Set property 'System.Windows.Setter.Value' threw an exception.`

It's position points to this line:

```
<Setter Property="MouseOverState" Value="{TemplateBinding NormalState}"/>
```

Here's part of the XAML code, which is located in a `ResourceDictionary`:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ImageButton}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ImageButton}">
                    <Grid>
                        <ContentControl>
                            <Grid>
                                <Image x:Name="Normal" Source="{TemplateBinding NormalState}" Visibility="Visible"/>
                                <Image x:Name="MouseOver" Source="{TemplateBinding MouseOverState}" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                                <Image x:Name="Pressed" Source="{TemplateBinding PressedState}" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                                <Image x:Name="Disabled" Source="{TemplateBinding DisabledState}" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ContentControl>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=MouseOverState}" Value="{x:Null}">
                            <Setter Property="MouseOverState" Value="{TemplateBinding NormalState}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="50"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="Normal" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="MouseOver" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="Pressed" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="Disabled" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                        </Trigger>

...and so on...
```

Here's the use code:

In the template code you may notice the `Setter` of `Width` to the value of `50`.  This was done to check if that code detects missing `ouseOverState` property at all; and it does.  However, when I try to set the MouseOverState property, I get the Setter Exception described above.  Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong or is there an easier way?  I couldn't figure out a way to do it with the control's code-behind within the dependency property code (that dependency code is pretty common to all other, so I'm not going to post it here, unless it's requested).

Here's another way I tried, but it did not work either (throwing the same exception, which does not provide a whole lot of details):

```
<Setter TargetName="Normal" Property="Source" Value="{TemplateBinding NormalState}"/>
```

I couldn't find a way, after much searching, of accomplishing this task within the C# code using Dependency Property setters either.  However, if someone knows of it, that'll be a very acceptable solution as well.

Comment: Could you not use the Fallback value in the Metadata of the dependency property?

Comment: @MartinGrundy I will take a look at that.  I'm new to dependency properties, so I didn't know that it had that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **TemplateBinding** can only be used within a ControlTemplate.TemplateBinding is used for binding to the element properties within the template definition.**Setters** do not support TemplateBinding.
>
> ---
>
> A TemplateBinding is an optimized form of a Binding for template scenarios, analogous to a Binding constructed with {Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}.
>
> Visit this [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84278/how-do-i-use-wpf-bindings-with-relativesource) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24889834/wpf-trigger-from-a-different-control/24890096?noredirect=1#comment38663405_24890096) for binding
>
> ---
>
> in your case try with
>
> ```
> <Setter TargetName="Normal" Property="Source" Value="{Binding Path=Propertyname, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:ImageButton}}"/>
> ```
>
> **or**
>
> ```
>    <Setter TargetName="Normal" Property="Source" Value="{Binding Path=Propertyname,  RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
> ```